# Node.js: Передать изображение с сервера на браузер

Tags: javascript, node.js, изображения, сервер, canvas

Нужно передать изображение с сервера на браузер. Для этого я передаю браузер массив, в котором содержится локальный путь до изображения. Пользователь может изменять путь до папки с изображениями

Server.js: считываю и записываю в массив путь до изображений находящийся в папке images

```
fs.readdir("../../Desktop/images",{ withFileTypes: true },
(err, files) => {
    if (err)
        console.log(err);
    else {
        files.forEach(file => {
            if (path.extname(file.name) === ".jpg") {
                var imgpath = '../../Desktop/images/' + file.name
                images.push(imgpath)
            }
        })
    }
});
```

Передаем браузеру массив, который содержит пути

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
   res.render('index', {images: images, index_img: index_img, category: setting["category"]})

});
```

Но при попытке вывести изображение на канвас, ничего не выводится.

```
var img_element = new Image()
img_element.src = current_image // в переменной current_image лежит путь до изображения
```

В итоге в логах выходится ошибка: 70-b3-d05_1_75_0.jpg :1 GET http://locallhost:8080/Desktop/images/70-b3-d05_1_75_0.jpg 404 (Not Found)
Подскажите в чем проблема и как ее решить? Или, возможно, есть какой-нибудь более рациональный способ отправить браузеру массив с фотографиями

```
app.use('/Desktop', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,images[index_img]))
})
```

Comment: а где серверный обработчик адресов вида `http://locallhost:8080/Desktop/images/70-b3-d05_1_75_0.jpg`?

Comment: app.use('/Desktop', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,images[index_img]))
}) Фотография отображается, но только одна - самая первая. index_img = 0. В приложении можно листать фотографии, получается при каждом пролистовании нужно отправлять запрос серверу, чтобы он изменил счетчик index_img?

Comment: Проблема решилась

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решилась добавлением следующей строки : index_img = index_img + 1

```
app.use('/Desktop', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,images[index_img]))
    index_img = index_img + 1 // вот этой строки
})
```